# How to Pass Value from a Statefull Widget to a Contoller while redirecting to Screen View in Flutter and Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, model-view-controller, flutter-getx

I am Developing a Quiz.

Where User Choses Subject > Chapter

Then from  Chapter Info Page  > Start Quiz.

I am able to fetch the Subject ID and Chapter ID  and When the User Clicks on Start Quiz Button Present in Chapter Info

Quiz Starts

Quiz is based on MVC Pattern

Here I am Redirecting user to Quiz Screen from Chapter Info page

How to access Value from Statefull widget  ChapterInfo  to a  QuizContoller

```
onPressed: () {
  Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => TopicWiseQuizScreen(quizSubjectID:subjectId,CatID: catId),
    ),
  );
},

class TopicWiseQuizScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TopicWiseQuizScreen({super.key, required quizSubjectID, required int CatID});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    TopicWiseQuestionController _controller = Get.put(TopicWiseQuestionController());
    return Scaffold()}}

class TopicWiseQuestionController extends GetxController
with SingleGetTickerProviderMixin {

    late final   int subID;
    late final   int catID;
```

Comment: Don't post screenshots of your code. Please paste your code snippet!

Answer (score 0):

After passing the values as parameters to your stateful widget you can access them by:

```
widget.quizSubjectID;
widget.catID;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should never create a `StatefulWidget` widget while using GetX because in GetX you can basically do anything using `StatelessWidget`.

But if you really want to pass a value to controller from `StatefulWidget` then you can assign those values in while navigating to the view like this:

**Controller**

```js
class DemoController extends GetxController {
  DemoController();

  Rx<int> quizSubjectID = 0.obs;
  Rx<int> catID = 0.obs;
}
```

Now you can set the controller values before navigating to the other screen like this:

**View**

```js
onPressed: () {
       final logic = Get.put(DemoController());
       logic.quizSubjectID.value = subjectId;
       logic.catID.value = catId;
       Navigator.push(
       context,
       MaterialPageRoute(
       builder: (context) => TopicWiseQuizScreen(quizSubjectID:subjectId,CatID: catId),
                ),
            );
       },
```

But try to use `StatelessWidgets` and pass data using `arguments` in GetX. There's also documentation available on `pub.dev` GetX package.